# How can I make this slider lower?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have this site:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

On the right side you will find your slider (a bottle). I want to make that slider smaller (about 70% of the `.right` div)

I put a picture to understand better what they want to do.

[image]

I use wordpress plugin `CPT Bootstrap Carousel` .In the first page and I have another slider (all with this plugin) ... should not affect the CSS code that slider.

I tried to add this code...but you can not look good ... I try to see as it is.

```
.right>#cptbc_791{height:70%;}
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `height` to the main `div` of the slider?

```
.parent{
  height:500px!important
}

.slider{ max-height:70%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.right .carousel-inner{height: 70%!important;max-width: 20%;}
```

^Remove the max-width if you want it to fill the parent. Hope this helps you out.